# What does Netbeans profiler's "Self Time" actually mean?

Tags: netbeans, profiling

I have been interested in time my simple game needs to run so I have used the Netbeans Java profiler (Java 1.7) and I can see the "Self Time" and "Invocations" columns in "Hot Spots" tab.

For example, my render method has:

**Self Time**: 1025 ms

**Invocations**: 2311

So, if I understand well, does it actually mean that the TOTAL amount of time of ALL render method invocations together gives 1025 ms and the average time of one method execution is 1025 / 2311 = **0,44 ms**?

If so, can I force the IDE to display average times instead of total times?

Comment: Why do you want it to display the average if your goal is to reduce the total?

Comment: Well, if I have a game loop implemented in a method, I might like to see how much time does one execution (frame) take...

Comment: Yes, you need to divide. However, running the profiler in instrumentation mode (or, actually, running it at all), influences performance (such as preventing JIT optimizations), and is not terribly useful. Manual timing/benchmarking (eg, calling System.nanoTime) can be better but is also fraught with problems.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Typically, "self time" measures the time spent *inside* the method body--excluding the time spent in the methods it calls. For example, say you had a simple method to retrieve the sorted users, `getUsers`, which called two methods that didn't make any other calls themselves.

```
UserList getUsers() {
    return sortUsers(loadUsers());
}
```

Since `getUsers` does no work, its self time would be very low even though calling the method is expensive.

```
Method       Self Time  Call Time
-----------  ---------  ---------
getUsers          3 ms   1,184 ms
loadUsers       923 ms     923 ms
sortUsers       258 ms     258 ms
```

This is based on other profiles I've used--not NetBeans. Hopefully someone can confirm or deny this for NetBeans itself.

Comment: Note: Methods which are inlined will count toward the *parent's* self-time and not be reported. Unless the mere presence of the profiler causes the JIT to un-inline those methods and you'll see overall performance drop. The profiler is not very useful to understand the performance of core, time-critical methods. Microbenchmarking (ie, without the profiler being involved) is better, although tricky to do right.